# Find people who have children in common and form couples

Tags: prolog

I am learning prolog and I have the following facts:

```
parent(joseph,thiago).
parent(camilla,thiago).
parent(joseph,wanda).
parent(camilla,wanda).
parent(lucas,flora).
parent(joana,flora).
parent(thiago,davi).
parent(flora,davi).
```

I'm trying to find couples based on this rule: "A couple is made up of two people who have children in common."

```
couple(X,Y) :- 
    parent(X,Z),
    parent(Y,Z),
    write(X), write(' and '), write(Y), write(' are a couple.'), nl, false.
```

The problem is that some results are returning repeated parents, such as:

```
"joseph and joseph are a couple!"
```

Comment: what happens if you add (before the first write-literal) X\=Y?

Comment: view: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66528247/interpreting-basic-prolog-result/66528806#66528806